# Compilation errors with CImg

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, cimg

I am using the CImg library for the first time and I get compilation errors with a simple test program that just includes CImg.h. Why is that? How can I fix this?

Program code:

```
#include "../headers/CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
In function 'FILE* cimg_library::cimg::fopen(const char*, const char*)':
5065|error: '_fileno' was not declared in this scope
In function 'int cimg_library::cimg::fseek(FILE*, INT_PTR, int)':
5093|error: '_fseeki64' was not declared in this scope
In function 'INT_PTR cimg_library::cimg::ftell(FILE*)':
5102|error: '_ftelli64' was not declared in this scope
```

This was done on a PC with a 64 bit Windows 8.1.

Command:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11  -c "D:\informatics\Projects\image experiments\Rectangle to circle stretcher\sources\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\sources\main.o
```

I tried this without the `-std=c++11` part and I get 2 errors instead of 3. I don't get `5065|error: '_fileno' was not declared in this scope`. Same happens if I replace it with `-std=gnu++11`

I also tried it on my laptop, which runs a 64 bit version of windows 7, and the same happens there.

So far, I have a work around for the first error, but nothing for the other two.

Comment: How did you try to compile it - what was your command? What platform are you on?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Edited.

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdio.h>` as your first line maybe.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I am just guessing using *comments* rather than answering, but maybe we will get there this way. Try adding `#include <cstdio>` as your first line. Try adding some, or all of these to your compile command `-Dcimg_display=0` near the start, and/or `-lgdi32` at the end.

Comment: Not sure how you installed `g++`, but you probably need to tell the compiler where the header files are (i.e. the include files). You probably need to add `-I /path/to/includes` and `-L /path/to/libs` to your compile command so that it can actually find the header files - not only CImg but also the system standard C++ header files.

Comment: #include <cstdio>, -Dcimg_display=0 and -lgdi32 didn't work. And I am not sure what you mean in the last comment. I have never done such things before and it has worked. If it matters, I am using Code::Blocks.

Comment: Ok, last attempt. Try changing `-std=c++11` to `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: Still the same errors. Is there any sort of tutorial that shows everything, including setting the library up and stuff like that? I am going to try this on my other PC to see what happens there. Going to post an update then.

Comment: I am confused, you said you were using a `g++` command and now you say you are using Code::Blocks. Can you try the `g++` command you said you were using just at the command-line outside of Code::Blocks so we can rule out any Code::Blocks effects? Also, with `-std=gnu++11`.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I meant to say that I was using Code::Blocks at first. But after I got the errors that I started doing everything in the command line and still got the same errors.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I tried it again with '-std=gnu++11' and it appears that I have missed the fact that the first error disappeared.

Comment: Can you compile the first pinky/purple example code shown here? Nothing at all to do with CImg. http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-system.html I still think the problem is that your compiler cannot find the `cstdio` header file.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes, I can even with '-std=c++11'. I read about the first error and it seems to be some sort of bug with cstdio and the work around is to use '-std=gnu++11'. https://github.com/dtschump/CImg/issues/43 However, I have not seen the other two errors mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of CodeBlock 16.01 *stdio.h* contains lines

```
#if __MSVCRT_VERSION__ >= 0x800
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW     _fseek_nolock (FILE*, long, int);
_CRTIMP long __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    _ftell_nolock (FILE*);

_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW     _fseeki64 (FILE*, __int64, int);
_CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _ftelli64 (FILE*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW     _fseeki64_nolock (FILE*, __int64, int);
_CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _ftelli64_nolock (FILE*);
#endif
```

i.e. those functions are not declared unless `__MSVCRT_VERSION__` is at least 0x800. The following might work (at least it did for CodeBlocks 16.01)

```
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x800
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#endif

// if needed
// #define _fileno fileno

#include "CImg.h"
```

If *stdio.h* does not contain declaration for `_fseeki64` and others,  either

- Use CImg 1.6.9 that does not use `_fseeki64`,
- upgrade gcc/g++, or
- provide an own implementation for `_fseeki64` (if such one can be found somewhere).

Comment: I just want to point out that I don't use the default compiler thjat comes with Code::Blocks, but rather a 64 bit version of MinGW, so should I change any part of that? (I tried it with the default one as well and I get the same errors.)

Comment: @indjev99 You should probably edit your question to include specific details about your development environment. If file *stdio.h* does not have a declaration for `_fseeki64`, earlier version of CImg (1.6.9) might work since it doesn't call `_fseeki64`.

Comment: @indjev99 I did actually test my solution with 64bit g++ v5.4.0 (msys2 environment), and compiling worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I understand what the `#define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x800` line is for, but why do we need the next one (`#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500`)? I tried it and it works without it.

Comment: @indjev99 I think it can be left out (or at least define it as 0x502 corresponding to windows xp sp2 / server 2003 sp2). That definition and `WINVER` may affect what library functions and definitions are available when compiling. [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx)